# Split array and insert to database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have array like this

```
$group=[['abc','cde','01/03/2019','01/05/2019'],['123','456','01/23/2019','01/30/2019']];
```

I want to insert to database by 4 field like this:

```
field1     field2      field3        field4
 abc         cde     01/03/2019    01/05/2019
 123         456     01/23/2019    01/30/2019
```

I try these code:

```
for($j=1;$j<count($groups);$j++){
    for ($k=0; $k < count($groups[$j]) ; $k++) { 
        $insert = array(
           'activity' => $groups[$j][$k],
           'person' => $groups[$j][$k],
           'startdate' => $groups[$j][$k],
           'finishdate' => $groups[$j][$k]
        );
    DB::table('test_tbl')->insert($insert);
    }
}
```

any solution for this thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Foreach

I would suggest you make use of the ForEach loop:

```
foreach($group as $item){
  $insert = array(
    'activity' => $item[0],
    'person' => $item[1],
    'startdate' => $item[2],
    'finishdate' => $item[3]
  );

  DB::table('test_tbl')->insert($insert);

}
```

This way you don't need to count the array and the code is nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way in this case would just be to hard code your indexes.

Like so:

```
for($j = 0;  $j  < count($groups); $j++){

  $insert = array(
    'activity' => $groups[$j][0],
    'person' => $groups[$j][1],
    'startdate' => $groups[$j][2],
    'finishdate' => $groups[$j][3]
  );

  DB::table('test_tbl')->insert($insert);

}
```

In a FOR loop your index counter `$j` will generally start at 0.  So be careful with that going forward.

Comment: Yup no problem, hope it helps.  ~Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How about foreach?

```
foreach ($group as $item){
  $insert = array(
           'activity' => $item[0],
           'person' => $item[1],
           'startdate' => $item[2],
           'finishdate' => $item[3]
        );
    DB::table('test_tbl')->insert($insert);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
array_map(function($item){
   DB::table('table_name')->insert([
      'activity'   => $item[0],
      'person'     => $item[1],
      'startdate'  => $item[2],
      'finishdate' => $item[3]
   ]);
}, $groups);
```